# Selenium closing the brower alone after finishing all the function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm pretty new in programming so I might be an easy question, but I don't understand why the browsers opened by Selenium closes at the end of the code.

```
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver

from selenium import webdriver

def Online_PLatform():
   
    Driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    Driver.get('https://elearningmarikina.ph/')

    Gmail = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/input')

    Gmail.send_keys('958rectin@depedmarikina.com')

    Pass = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input')

    Pass.send_keys('33112')

    Button = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/button')

    Button.click()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use 2 approaches in order to keep you driver open.
1.
Add the 'detach' option to your driver settings:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

2. 

Simply add a delay at the end of your test code (less elegant approach but more simple)

```py
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver

from selenium import webdriver
import time

def Online_PLatform():
   
    Driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    Driver.get('https://elearningmarikina.ph/')

    Gmail = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/input')

    Gmail.send_keys('958rectin@depedmarikina.com')

    Pass = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input')

    Pass.send_keys('33112')

    Button = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/button')

    Button.click()

    time.sleep(50)
```

Comment: Why did you do import the time module?

Comment: That's quite obviously, but you are right, now i wrote that explicitly

Comment: For 1, remember to add the chrome_options instance to your Driver: `Driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)`

Answer (score 1):

`This is because after the all functions, The code stops running and that's why selenium exits.`

`You can use the time module to delay.`

```py
import time
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver

from selenium import webdriver

def Online_PLatform():
   
    Driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    Driver.get('https://elearningmarikina.ph/')

    Gmail = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/input')

    Gmail.send_keys('958rectin@depedmarikina.com')

    Pass = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input')

    Pass.send_keys('33112')

    Button = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/button')

    Button.click()
    time.sleep(50) #---> 50 second delay
```